# Cancel sync request in grpc python client

Tags: python, client, grpc

I am creating grpc python client with sync long-lived GET request:

```
def main():
    with grpc.insecure_channel(target='localhost:50051') as channel:
        stub = hello_pb2_grpc.HelloStub(channel)

        def signal_handler(signal, frame):
            print("")
            logging.warning("Interrupt signal. Exiting!")
            channel.close()
            sys.exit(0)

        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    ...
        while True:
            logging.info("Sending request for control")
            try:
                resp = stub.GetControl(hello_pb2.GetControlRequest(
                    node=node_id
                ))
                print("Got response: {}".format(resp))
    ...
```

if user will close python client with *Ctrl-C* and start client again, it will reconnect to grpc server with different port.

Question is: how client should notify grpc server about its exit, so the server should "drop" previous connection?

After few client re-connection, from server logs I can see that server tries to send response to non existing peer without any errors:

```
INFO[0153] finished unary call with code OK              grpc.code=OK grpc.method=GetControl grpc.service=world.World grpc.start_time="2021-02-19T12:41:17+01:00" grpc.time_ms=75479.79 peer.address="127.0.0.1:59976" span.kind=server system=grpc

INFO[0159] finished unary call with code OK              grpc.code=OK grpc.method=GetControl grpc.service=world.World grpc.start_time="2021-02-19T12:41:05+01:00" grpc.time_ms=94089.74 peer.address="127.0.0.1:59862" span.kind=server system=grpc
```

Note: peer addresses/ports are different.

Using client async method *stub.GetControl* will return immediately `future`, which can be canceled at any time `future.cancel()`

Answer (score 0):

The cancel API is only available in the async method. The sync API is intended to finish all the work before returning, so it can't be cancelled. BTW, if you want to notify the server, why not explicitly send an RPC? The `GetControl` method you are using is a unary call, which shouldn't take long to finish. If you want a more interactive communication between client/server, please give streaming RPC API a try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is useful for you  but when a RPC is cancelled, gRPC does not terminate the service thread. Therefore,  RPC request will continue to be processed on the server side. However, you may use `context.add_callback()` by combining it with `threading.Event()` method to setup a listener for detecting done/canceled RPC calls. When the event is set you can return or raise and exception.

```
stop_event = threading.Event()

def on_rpc_done():
    stop_event.set()

context.add_callback(on_rpc_done)


does_some_process(stop_event)
```

```
def does_some_process(stop_event):

  for i in range(0,10):
     if stop_event.is_set():
         return # Or raise
```

You can find more detailed example [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/cancellation/README.md)